# Unity & Leap Motion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, leap-motion, gesturedetector

I want to make a game in **Unity**. The concept is to identify a motion with **Leap Motion**. It will have 10 rounds and to move to the next round you must do the correct motion. Also it is not necessary to be a motion. I think about **Extended Finger Detector**. Do you have any idea how to make the connect every round with a motion?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to simplify problems into easy solutions.

Define a `class Round` containing the 5 finger states you like.
For example in round 1 Thumb is Extended and the rest not.

Make a `List<Round> roundList` with 10 elements, constructing or initializing them with valid states according to rounds basing on your intended "gestures".

During a specific round, call a function `checkFingers(int n)` that compares the 5 fingers states from the round `n` in `roundList[n]` with the Finger States returned by the Extended Finger Detector script component.

If they match, the function returns true and the round is passed.